# Redis sorted set combine

Tags: redis

Redis is awesome !

If I have 2 sorted sets like - "set1 = key1:100, key2:200, key3:300"

and another like "set2 = key1:1, key2:2, key3:3"

then is it possible to get like this - set3 = key1:100_1, key2:200_2, key3:300_3

I do not want to add values of same key or take min/max of same key. 
Is it possible to get these values together ?
I want to get both of these values in together for that same key.

Answer (score 1):

A score in a sorted set has to be a numerical value, so it is not possible to return a simple concatenation of the scores in intersection/union operations.

However, if you can bound the value of the scores for each set to a given range, it is possible to use the SUM operation to encode two values in a single value with simple arithmetic.

Example:

```
# For s1, we assume the score is between 0 and 999
> zadd s1 100 key1 200 key2 300 key3
(integer) 3
# For s2, we assume the score is between 0 and 99
> zadd s2 1 key1 2 key2 3 key3
(integer) 3

# Get the intersection, dividing the s2 score by 100
> zinterstore s3 2 s1 s2 WEIGHTS 1 0.01
(integer) 3

# Get the result with scores
> zrange s3 0 -1 withscores
1) "key1"
2) "100.01000000000001"
3) "key2"
4) "200.02000000000001"
5) "key3"
6) "300.02999999999997"
```

In the resulting scores, the integer part contains the score coming from s1, the fractional part contains the score coming from s2.

Please note the score is a double floating point number. It has some consequences:

- you may have to round it properly if you manipulate only integers (i.e. 0.0299999... is actually 0.03)
- encoding two numerical values in one means the precision is divided by 2 (16 digits to 8 digits only). It may or may not suit your needs.